# Solve a linear system of three variables and represent the solution in parametric form

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve the system
\begin{cases}
\phantom6x_1 + \phantom7x_2 + 3x_3 = 5,\\[0.3em]
        6x_1 +         7x_2 - 3x_3 = 5;
\end{cases}

I need the solution in the form of
\begin{cases}
x_1=\color{gray}{\text{blank}}+\color{gray}{\text{blank}}\times s;\\[0.3em]
x_2=\color{gray}{\text{blank}}+\color{gray}{\text{blank}}\times s;\\[0.3em]
x_3=\color{gray}{\text{blank}}+\color{gray}{\text{blank}}\times s.
\end{cases}

Very similar to a question I have previously asked with two variables. My attempt is to set it up in a matrix and eliminate:

\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & \phantom-3 & 5 \\
6 & 7 &         -3 & 5 \\
\end{array}\right]
%
\begin{array}{}\\+\text{row}_1\end{array}\\
\iff&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 3 & \phantom15 \\
7 & 8 & 0 &         10 \\
\end{array}\right]
%
\begin{array}{}\\-7\text{row}_1\end{array}\\
\iff&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & \phantom{-2}3 & \phantom{-2}5 \\
0 & 1 &           -21 &           -25 \\
\end{array}\right]
%
\begin{array}{}-\text{row}_2\\{}\end{array}\\
\iff&\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & \phantom-24 & \phantom-30 \\
0 & 1 &         -21 &         -25 \\
\end{array}\right]
%
\begin{array}{}\\.\end{array}
\end{align}

Would I then end up with the following?

\begin{cases}
x_1 = \phantom-  30 -         24s,\\[0.3em]
x_2 =           -25 +         21s,\\[0.3em]
x_3 = \phantom{-2}0 + \phantom20s.
\end{cases}

Answer (score 1):

You should set $x_3 = s$.

Think of $x_3$ as a free variable. You started with two equations and three unknowns; this means you have (at least) one free variable. It didn't have to be $x_3$, but it might as well be.

When you write $x_3 = 0+0s$, you are saying $x_3$ has to be zero for the system to hold; while in fact $x_3$ can take on any value, and the system will be satisfied as long as $x_1$ and $x_2$ behave correctly according to $x_3$ (or $s$).

Comment: I follow the setting x3=s, but not sure how that would then apply to answering in the format that is required.

Comment: $x_3 = s$ is the same as $x_3 = 0+1\cdot s$, which is the correct format @davidscidmore

Comment: Thank you very much, I just wasn't sure if that was what it needed to be. You also helped me with about 5 different problems since my instructor seems to not care. @gaussthebauss.

Comment: @davidscidmore you are welcome